# java.io.StreamCorruptedException In Android

Tags: java, android

I have a question about my code.
 It doesnt work perfectly
Error Comes From this Line

```
ObjectInputStream obin=new ObjectInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

please help me guys

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        loginButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0== loginButton) {
            loadSettings();
        }
    }

    private void loadSettings(){
        try {
            String uname=username.getText().toString();
            String upass=new String(password.getText().toString());

            if (uname.equals("") || uname.equals(null) ||upass.equals("") ||upass.equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                postParameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("upass", upass));

                post("http://192.168.1.3:8080/and/log", postParameters);  

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString()+".....Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void post(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters){
        try {



            HttpClient client=getHttpClient();

            HttpPost request=new HttpPost(url);

            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

            request.setEntity(formEntity);

            HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);

            ObjectInputStream obin=new ObjectInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

            //ObjectInputStream obin=new ObjectInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

            final HashMap hm=(HashMap) obin.readObject();

            if (hm.get("status").toString().equals("OK")) {             
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(hm.get("status").toString().equals("NO")) {                
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString()+"...............", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }

    private HttpClient getHttpClient(){
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams params=mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }
```

This Is Java Servlet

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        try {


            String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
            String upass=request.getParameter("upass");
            System.out.println(upass);

            ObjectOutputStream obut = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            HashMap hm = new HashMap();

            if(uname.equals("p") && upass.equals("123")){
            hm.put("status", "OK");
            }else{
            hm.put("status", "NO");
            }
            obut.writeObject(hm); 
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }}

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

First converting into String, then you will do what you want. for example I am converting into json object.

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse.trim());
```